# how to export tm object without chart borders

Tags: r, rgdal, tmap

I am trying to plot a map without the 'box border' around it.

Does anybody know how to work around the `tmap` package to not print the 'outer box border'?  - not to be confused with `tm_borders` as it is a segment plotting the border of the polygons in the map.

Here's my example code:

```
tm_obj <- tm_shape(area_spdf) + 
          tm_fill(col = var, palette = "Blues", legend.show = FALSE) +
          tm_borders(col = "burlywood4", lwd = 0.25)`

save_tmap(tm = tm_obj, 
          filename = paste("plot_tm_output_", var, ".png", sep = ""))`
```

[image]

Comment: By any chance we can set the background to be transparent too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `tm_layout` to specify not to draw frame:

```
 tm_obj <- tm_shape(area_spdf) + 
           tm_fill(col = var, palette = "Blues", legend.show = FALSE) +
           tm_borders(col = "burlywood4", lwd = 0.25) +
           tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! I am not very familiar with `tmap`